# picking random image from resources

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Hi I am working on simple android app. App is contained of only image view. On image view click picture that is shown should be changed. My question is how can i get the list of resources or resource image by index. For example in drawable I have 100 images name from s1 - s100. And i want to display one of them using random function like this:

```
private void ImageView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int index = r.Next() % 100;

            //code where I get picture on "index place" from my drawable folder.
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you already have accepted answer, but it's a very boring way to achieve what u want because it needs the developer to write the array with all hundreds of items. A much simpler way of achieving it is to getting the identifier for the drawable directly.

I'm not sure on Xamarin/C# how that would be, but on Java you use like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
int index = r.nextInt(100);
String name = "s" + index;
int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                    name,               // the name of the resource
                    "drawable",         // type of resource
                    getPackageName())); // your app package name
imageView.setImageResource(drawableId);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create any arrays.xml file in values and add your drawables into an array like this

```
<integer-array name="images">
    <item>@drawable/drawable1</item>
    <item>@drawable/drawable2</item>
    <item>@drawable/drawable3</item>
</integer-array>
```

Then in your activity class add this

```
TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);

// get resource id by random index i
images.getResourceId(i, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take one array of integer to store all drawables

```
int resIds = new int[]{R.drawable.s1, R.drawable.s2, .... R.drawable.s100};
```

Then calculate random index and pick drawable from that index

```
Random r = new Random();
int index = r.Next(resIds.length -1);
imageView.setImageResource(resIds[index]);
```

Comment: Do I have to add using statement in order to get access to R?

Comment: Why did you accept this answer? Who wants to make such an integer array? The answer of @Budius is where you were after. And the best answer has not even been posted as one can simply list the content of the drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most elegant solution, @Budius gave it in Java, this is C#:

```
private void ImageView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int index = r.Next() % 36;
            String name = "s" + index;
            int drawableId = Resources.GetIdentifier(
                                name,               // the name of the resource
                                "drawable",         // type of resource
                                "Us.Us"); // your app package name
            imageView.SetImageResource(drawableId);

        }
```

> "Us.Us" is my package name.

Comment: it looks like mine answer. just saying.

Comment: @Budius My apologies. I miss looked. Thanks